# String Method and loops

Tags: java

I have a program I'm working on that I'm stuck on and can't really figure out. Basically, I'm supposed to input a word, and have the word be encased in a box of asterisks, which is the main objective. The actual prompt says: Read a string from the keyboard.  Output the string centered inside of a box as shown below.  The box needs to be resized on each run to assure that it has the correct spacing.

Ex.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Prog600a
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            for(int i = 1; i<=3; i++)
            {
                Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in); //Allows input
                System.out.print("Enter a string: "); 
                String word1 = kbReader.nextLine();
                int len1 = word1.length();
            for(int x = 0; x<=len1; x++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("*");
            for(int x = 0; x<len1; x++)
            {
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
            System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("* " + word1 + " *");
            System.out.print("*");
            for(int x = 0; x<len1; x++)
            {
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
            System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();
            for(int x = 0; x<len1; x++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the string method length to determine how long the string is, and print asterisks according to that. However, I can't seem to get the spacing, and my output looks nothing like the one shown. I've been experimenting with the code for a few hours (which is why it's a bit long and may be inefficient ), but can't really seem to get it. The spacing isn't right, and I don't really know how to correctly resize the box on each run. Can someone please provide some guidance? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Could you post examples of what you want it to look like and what you are getting?  I'm a little confused by the tabs.

Comment: `\t` is a tab. You should just be using `" "` for a space to make everything consistent. A tab is bigger than other characters

Answer (score 5):

I spot only tiny problems:

1. You don't print enough asterisks in the top and the bottom (make it `< len1 + 4`)
2. You print tabs instead of spaces (change `"\t"` to `" "`).
3. You don't print enough spaces, change those loops to `< len + 2`

That's all. My output for input `test`:

```
********
*      *
* test *
*      *
********
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overlow isn't for doing your homework for you. But, I will give you some pointers:

Look at [repeat](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

A tab character is 4-8 characters long, depending on how you're viewing it. '*' is one character long.